# Basketball - two players with no turns

Tags: probability

> Two players are shooting free throws. The game ends when one of them
>   scores and the other one misses, and the winner is the one who scores.
>   Suppose player A has a probability of $p$ to score and player B has a
>   probability of $q$. All throws are independent.
>
> 1. What is the probability that player A wins?
> 2. What is the probability that player A wins, given he scored in the
>          first round?

As for part 1, I denoted $X,Y$ as the random variables for the final score of  players A,B, respectively. So according to the description of the game, A wins iff $X-Y=1$, thus:

$\Pr (X-Y=1)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\Pr (X=k+1,Y=k)\\=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\Pr (X=k+1)\Pr(Y=k)=p\cdot \sum_{k=0}^\infty(pq)^k = {p \over 1-pq} $

As for part 2, it doesn't seem that conditioning $\Pr (X-Y=1|X\geq1)$ would lead to a different result.

So I guess my approach is problematic - I can't help to think that I'm not considering the rounds where they both missed. 
On the other hand, any method in which I tried to incorporate the total number of games as a geometric variable with prob. $p(1-q)+q(1-p)$ evantually turned out to be very messy.

Would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: For the first problem, if $p=q$ then the answer must be $\frac 12$ by symmetry...but that's not what your formula yields.  Also note that the sum of the probabilities for $A's$ and $B's$ victory must be $1$, but again that's not what your formula yields.

Comment: As a hint for solving the first part:  note that we only care about the rounds in which exactly one player scores.  Compute the probability of that and the portion of that probability which is explained by $A$ winning.

Comment: For the second part, knowing that $A$ scores in the first round increases the probability that $A$ will win the game in the first round.  After that round, we are back to normal.

Comment: You could note $X$ (resp. $Y$) the rank that player A (resp. B) first miss. Then event "A wins" is just $X>Y$ (and not $X=Y+1$).

Comment: @lulu I thought about that, denoting the events $A$ as "the game ends at *some* round" and $B$ as "player A won at that round" gives us: $\Pr (B|A)={p(1-q) \over p(1-q)+q(1-p)}$, but it doesn't seem quite accurate.

Answer (score 1):

1)

Think of it as if they keep on going also if someone has won already.

Let $D_n$ denote the event that at the $n$-th round both players score or both players do not score.

Let $A_n$ denote the event that at the $n$-th round $\mathbf A$ scores and $\mathbf B$ does not.

Let $A$ denote the event that $\mathbf A$ wins the game.

Then: $$A=A_1\cup(D_1\cap A_2)\cup(D_1\cap D_2\cap A_3)\cup\cdots$$

So that: $$P(A)=P(A_1)+P(D_1)P(A_2)+P(D_1)P(D_2)P(A_3)+\cdots=$$$$P(A_1)[1+P(D_1)+P(D_1)^2+\cdots]=\frac{P(A_1)}{1-P(D_1)}$$
Note that this equals $P(A_1\mid D^{\complement}_1)$ so matches with the hint of lulu.

More directly you can argue that: $$P(A)=P(A_1)+P(D_1)P(A)$$leading to the same result.

(If $\mathbf A$ does not win in the first round then with probability $P(D_1)$ he gets a second (and equal) chance on winning.)

2)

Here we find likewise:

$$P(A\mid \mathbf A\text{ scores at first round})=$$$$P(\mathbf B\text{ does not score at first round})+P(\mathbf B\text{ scores at first round})P(A)$$

Where $P(A)$ has been calculated at 1).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a related scenario that will help you think about your problem. A is the probability that player 1 will win a particular round of a game, B is the probability that player 2 will win a round, and C is the probability that the two players tie and have to repeat the round.  Then the probability that player 1 wins the round is the infinite series: $(A + AC + AC^2 + AC^3 + ...)$.  So factor A out and get $A(1 + C + C^2 + ...)$.  For 0 < C < 1, the infinite series $(1 + C + C^2 + ...)$ = $\frac{1}{1 - C}$.

The first question of your problem is worded slightly differently, but it is still the same.  You just have to compute A based on P and Q.  You have to compute C based on P and Q.

For the second question, let [Ans] be the answer to the first question.  Then the answer to the second question is (1 - Q) + Q*[Ans].  I.e. (1 - Q) being the probability that player 2 misses and the game is decided.  Q*[Ans] being the probability that player 2 makes his shot, and from there, the probability of victory from this point forward is the same as before.

Comment: don't you mean $p(1-q)$ in the second question? player 2 misses his shot but in order for player 1 to win in the first round, he must score.

Comment: gbi1977 no.  It is a conditional probability.  Player 1 hitting his first shot in the first round is a given.  It would be like if it asked "What is the probability that you flip a coin twice and it comes up heads first, then tails, given that the first flip was heads?"  The answer would be 1/2.  
$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$, in this case P(A|B) is what the question is asking for, the numerator is p(1-q), and the denominator is p.  
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#Kolmogorov_definition